# wagmi usePrepareContractWrite pass an struct argument in args: []

Tags: wagmi, rainbowkit

I have an error when trying to write to a contract by using usePrepareContractWrite by passing a struct, heres my struct

```
    class Job {
    
      id: BigNumber = BigNumber.from("-1");
      hasFunds: boolean = false;
      profileId: BigNumber = BigNumber.from("-1");
      title: string = "";
      description: string = "";
      documents: string[] = [];
      owner: Address = "0x";
      requester: Address = "0x";
      date: BigNumber = BigNumber.from("-1");
      datePaid: BigNumber = BigNumber.from("-1");
      img: string = "";
      requestedPaymentAmount: BigNumber = BigNumber.from("-1");
      token: Address = "0x";
    }
```

// js code

```
  const perp = usePrepareContractWrite({
    ...contractConfig,
    functionName: "createJob",
    args: [new Job()],
    enabled: true,
  });
```

// ad here's the error

```
    error: invalid value for array (argument="value", value=undefined, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=contracts/5.7.0)
    at Logger.makeError (index.js:224:1)
    at eval (index.js:71:1)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at eval (index.js:8:1)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (index.js:4:1)
    at resolveAddresses (index.js:57:1)
    at eval (index.js:60:1)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at eval (index.js:59:1)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at eval (index.js:8:1)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (index.js:4:1)
    at resolveAddresses (index.js:57:1)
    at eval (index.js:67:1)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at eval (index.js:8:1)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (index.js:4:1)
    at resolveAddresses (index.js:57:1)
    at eval (index.js:60:1)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at eval (index.js:59:1)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at eval (index.js:8:1)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (index.js:4:1)
    at resolveAddresses (index.js:57:1)
    at eval (index.js:120:1)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at eval (index.js:8:1)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (index.js:4:1)
    at populateTransaction (index.js:82:1)
    at eval (index.js:217:1)
    at prepareWriteContract (chunk-VQG3VKOR.js:2136:1)
    at Object.eval [as queryFn] (index.js:1646:32)
    at Object.fetchFn [as fn] (query.mjs:252:1)
    at run (retryer.mjs:101:1)
    at createRetryer (retryer.mjs:149:1)
    at Query.fetch (query.mjs:307:33)
    at QueryObserver.executeFetch (queryObserver.mjs:168:1)
    at QueryObserver.setOptions (queryObserver.mjs:86:1)
    at eval (index.js:184:1)
    at commitHookEffectListMount (react-dom.development.js:23150:1)
    at commitPassiveMountOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:24926:1)
    at commitPassiveMountEffects_complete (react-dom.development.js:24891:1)
    at commitPassiveMountEffects_begin (react-dom.development.js:24878:1)
    at commitPassiveMountEffects (react-dom.development.js:24866:1)
window.console.error @ next-dev.js:20
overrideMethod @ react_devtools_backend.js:2655
onError @ query.mjs:294
reject @ retryer.mjs:63
eval @ retryer.mjs:122
Promise.catch (async)
run @ retryer.mjs:106
createRetryer @ retryer.mjs:149
fetch @ query.mjs:307
executeFetch @ queryObserver.mjs:168
setOptions @ queryObserver.mjs:86
eval @ index.js:184
commitHookEffectListMount @ react-dom.development.js:23150
commitPassiveMountOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:24926
commitPassiveMountEffects_complete @ react-dom.development.js:24891
commitPassiveMountEffects_begin @ react-dom.development.js:24878
commitPassiveMountEffects @ react-dom.development.js:24866
flushPassiveEffectsImpl @ react-dom.development.js:27039
flushPassiveEffects @ react-dom.development.js:26984
commitRootImpl @ react-dom.development.js:26935
commitRoot @ react-dom.development.js:26682
performSyncWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:26117
flushSyncCallbacks @ react-dom.development.js:12042
eval @ react-dom.development.js:25651
setTimeout (async)
eval @ utils.mjs:287
sleep @ utils.mjs:286
scheduleMicrotask @ utils.mjs:296
flush @ notifyManager.mjs:59
batch @ notifyManager.mjs:25
dispatch @ query.mjs:439
setData @ query.mjs:44
onSuccess @ query.mjs:322
resolve @ retryer.mjs:54
Promise.then (async)
run @ retryer.mjs:106
createRetryer @ retryer.mjs:149
fetch @ query.mjs:307
executeFetch @ queryObserver.mjs:168
setOptions @ queryObserver.mjs:86
eval @ index.js:184
commitHookEffectListMount @ react-dom.development.js:23150
commitPassiveMountOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:24926
commitPassiveMountEffects_complete @ react-dom.development.js:24891
commitPassiveMountEffects_begin @ react-dom.development.js:24878
commitPassiveMountEffects @ react-dom.development.js:24866
flushPassiveEffectsImpl @ react-dom.development.js:27039
flushPassiveEffects @ react-dom.development.js:26984
commitRootImpl @ react-dom.development.js:26935
commitRoot @ react-dom.development.js:26682
performSyncWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:26117
flushSyncCallbacks @ react-dom.development.js:12042
eval @ react-dom.development.js:25651
setTimeout (async)
(anonymous) @ inpage.js:17
write @ inpage.js:17
b @ inpage.js:17
(anonymous) @ inpage.js:17
v.write @ inpage.js:17
g @ inpage.js:17
h @ inpage.js:8
o.emit @ inpage.js:8
_ @ inpage.js:17
w @ inpage.js:17
b.push @ inpage.js:17
_write @ inpage.js:1
b @ inpage.js:17
(anonymous) @ inpage.js:17
v.write @ inpage.js:17
g @ inpage.js:1
h @ inpage.js:8
o.emit @ inpage.js:8
_ @ inpage.js:1
w @ inpage.js:1
b.push @ inpage.js:1
_onData @ inpage.js:1
_onMessage @ inpage.js:1
postMessage (async)
_postMessage @ contentscript.js:1
_write @ contentscript.js:1
v @ contentscript.js:1
(anonymous) @ contentscript.js:1
y.write @ contentscript.js:1
g @ contentscript.js:17
h @ contentscript.js:8
o.emit @ contentscript.js:8
_ @ contentscript.js:17
w @ contentscript.js:17
v.push @ contentscript.js:17
_write @ contentscript.js:17
v @ contentscript.js:17
(anonymous) @ contentscript.js:17
y.write @ contentscript.js:17
g @ contentscript.js:17
h @ contentscript.js:8
o.emit @ contentscript.js:8
_ @ contentscript.js:17
w @ contentscript.js:17
v.push @ contentscript.js:17
_write @ contentscript.js:17
v @ contentscript.js:17
(anonymous) @ contentscript.js:17
y.write @ contentscript.js:17
g @ contentscript.js:17
h @ contentscript.js:8
o.emit @ contentscript.js:8
_ @ contentscript.js:17
w @ contentscript.js:17
v.push @ contentscript.js:17
_onMessage @ contentscript.js:8
(anonymous) @ contentscript.js:8
```

Comment: I have the same issue

Answer (score 1):

If you are using wagmi 1.x.x you need to change BigNumber instances:
https://wagmi.sh/react/migration-guide#bignumber--native-bigint